# XML to XLS - Output text file with adding header for each column

Tags: xslt, header

I have the following code working to get output in `.txt` file. But now need to add header for each column. How do I add a header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="query">
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:value-of select="DEPTID"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="DESCR"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="POSTED_TOTAL_AMT"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="FISCAL_YEAR"/>
    <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNTING_PERIOD"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**With existing code without Header:**

```
12345   General Administration  33709.7 2023    8
```

**After adding code with Header expecting:**

```
Cost Center Description             Total Amount    Fiscal Year   Period
12345       General Administration  33709.7         2023          8
```

Comment: Why can't you simply use `xsl:text` to add the header?

Comment: What is your input XML? This would be helpful for comprising a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just embed your header line as literal text. Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="query">
  <xsl:text>Cost Center&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Description&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Total Amount&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Fiscal year&#x9;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Period&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="row">
    <xsl:value-of select="DEPTID"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="DESCR"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="POSTED_TOTAL_AMT"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="FISCAL_YEAR"/><xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ACCOUNTING_PERIOD"/><xsl:value-of select="OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My XSLT might be a bit rusty... care to explain why not like that?

Comment: I'm assuming you were saying I'd get unwanted whitespace. I've put everything in <xsl:text/> elements now.

Comment: Why don't you simply put the entire header in a singe `xsl:text` element?

Comment: Good point. At some level, that's an implementation question for the OP.

Comment: A downvote (at least my downvote) does not reflect on you personally. It simply means that I think your answer is not useful. I already indicated what I consider to be a good answer, both in my comment to the question and in my previous comment here. I don't think it depends on what OP (who apparently has abandoned this anyway) has to say. I will gladly retract my downvote if you adjust your answer accordingly - or if you explain what advantage your approach offers. Or you could simply delete your answer and move on with your life.